# Hql query to filter collection data

Tags: left-join, hql

I have a Restaurant entity with a category and a list of Branches. I want to search all the Restaurants which are in specific area and category
So, I was doing

```
SELECT R 
FROM Restaurant AS R 
  LEFT JOIN R.branches AS branch 
WHERE R.category.name LIKE :category AND branch.name LIKE :branch
```

It was working fine but it just so happens to be that, when a new restaurant is added initially the restaurant has no branches but i want to show them in result .. I am not sure how to achieve that , how to get restaurants with matching category and branch (even if it doesn't have a branch) .

If it's not clear what i am trying to do, I am trying to do something like this ..

SELECT R 
    FROM Restaurant AS R 
      LEFT JOIN R.branches AS branch 
    WHERE R.category.name LIKE :category AND (branch is NULL OR branch.name LIKE :branch )

retrieve those restaurants with the given branch name and also containing those that don't have any branches associated. OR in other words if Any restaurant doesn't have any branch than return it to the result list along with those matching the searched area name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use extra join conditions using HQL **with** keyword:

```
SELECT R 
FROM Restaurant AS R 
  LEFT JOIN R.branches AS branch WITH branch IS NULL OR branch.name LIKE :branch
WHERE R.category.name LIKE :category
```

For more information look at the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins).

Comment: sorry, I am using jpa. Jpa doesn't have that with keyword.. Do you know the JPA WITH alternative ?

Comment: There seems to be JOIN ON keyword in JPQL similar to hqls JOIN WITH . I will try it .. let's see if it works